# Polynomials division

Tags: polynomials

Let $p$ be a real polynomial ($p\in\mathbb{R}[x])$, if

- 5 is the remainder of the division $\frac{p(x)}{x-2}$, and
- 2 is the remainder of the division $\frac{p(x)}{x-5}$

What is the reaminder of the division $\frac{p(x)}{(x-2)(x-5)}$?

I have tried it, but I have no idea... 
Thank you

Comment: Write $\,p(x) = (x-2)(x-5)q(x)+ax+b\,$ then plug in a couple of well chosen values for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(x)=(x−2)(x−5)q(x)+ax+b$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Since we know the remainder of $p(x)$ when divided by $x-2$ and $x-5$

we obtain the following
\begin{align}
p(2) &= (2-2)(2-5)q(2) + a(2)+b\\ &=  2a+b = 5  \label{a}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
p(5) &= (5-2)(5-5)q(5) + a(5)+b\\ &=  5a+b = 2 \label{b}
\end{align}

Solving the simultaneous equations \ref{a} and \ref{b}, we obtain $a = -1 \text{ and } b = 7$.

Hence, the remainder of the division $\frac{p(x)}{(x−2)(x−5)}$ is $-x + 7$.

Comment: Thank you, I am very grateful for your help!